# Communication between multiple applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

Say I have an angular SPA running inside a browser (window 1). And say that there's some activity that leads to us launching a separate angular application inside of a new window (opened by `$window.open()`) (window 2).

Windows 1 & 2 want to stay somewhat connected. They're running different applications but they're both dealing with the same subject matter. When one changes state, the other might need to react to that. And vice versa.

I'm looking for some good way for these two apps, in two separate browser windows, to send events back and forth.

Now, for fun, there might be another window (window 3) running the same application as window 1. This separate instance should not be interfered with in any way by windows 1 & 2. And, of course, window 3 could launch it's own equivalent of window 2 (window 4).

So windows 1 & 2 (running different apps) should be able to message back and forth. And windows 3 & 4 similarly. But 1 shouldn't affect 3 & 4, and so on.

The obvious relationship between them is that window 1 called `$window.open()` and window 2 can access `$window.opener` - so they can both access `window` objects - but how do I "angular-ise" up this situation?

The current implementation is using `$localStorage` and watching for storage events to link windows 1 & 2,but of course this completely fails the non-interference requirement once windows 3 & 4 show up.

Comment: Sounds like web sockets might fit the bill: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: @ChrisHardie - I'd hoped to keep it all client side, if possible.

Comment: Based on what I'm reading, I think you really need a server to mediate this conversation between all your clients.

Comment: You can use [messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) between the windows instead of having `$watch` on `$localStorage`. Be aware of the [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/x-doc-messaging) though.

Comment: intriguing...also have sessionStorage. Not sure how that plays with multiple windows ( ie each window has own session or not)

Comment: Believe it or not, you actually can bind between windows. I wrote a directive that does this on an iFrame: http://jsfiddle.net/ProLoser/y2Xd3/light/ not sure how that applies to what you're doing but might give you some ideas. No reason why you couldn't use this trick to dispatch Angular events.

Comment: @JonathanRowny very cool...iframe body empty in Firefox unfortunately

Comment: @charlietfl it works in firefox but you have change the template to `<iframe src="javascript:&nbsp;"></iframe>` because firefox freaks out about an iframe without a source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a good case for using application events.

You'll want one object to have a publish/subscribe interface:

```
var dispatcher = {
    subscriptions: {},

    publish: function(eventName, publisher, data) {
        // loop through subscribers and notify them, passing publisher and data
        // var subscriber = this.subscribers[eventName][i];
        // subscriber.callback.call(subscriber.context, publisher, data);
    },

    subscribe: function(eventName, context, callback) {
        this.subscriptions[eventName] = this.subscriptions[eventName] || [];
        this.subscriptions[eventName].push({
            context: context,
            callback: callback
        });
    }
};
```

When you open a new window, set this object reference as a property on the new window.

```
var win = window.open(...);
win.dispatcher = dispatcher;
```

Now each window, including the "top" window should have a global variable called `dispatcher` that you can use to subscribe to and publish events:

(from main window)

```
dispatcher.subcribe("item.added", this, function(publisher, data) {
    // "publisher" is the object publishing the event
    // "data" is arbitrary data passed along in the event
});
```

(from a sub window)

```
dispatcher.publish("item.added", this, {
    name: "Foo"
});
```

I haven't used AngularJS much yet, so I'm not sure if it comes with some sort of event framework outside of DOM events. There are a bunch of implementations of the pub/sub model in JavaScript, and you could probably throw a dart at a Google search and land on one. I created a simple JavaScript class library that might fit the bill. It has no external dependencies: https://github.com/gburghardt/events

**Advantages**

- Performs very well, as it doesn't rely on the HTTP request/response lifecycle
- Fairly simple to set up
- Cross browser support with no hacks or polyfills

**Disadvantages**

- If the main window closes, then your sub windows will lose their connection to the outside world and published events will fall on deaf ears.

Comment: This sort of pattern works good when you need to message a different Angular module in the same window too.

Comment: I'm new here, so I can't post a comment on Nicolas ABRIC's answer, but I can think of one disadvantage of using localStorage is that event data persists between page views. Data passed along in an event is meant to be transient in nature -- used and then discarded. Using localStorage makes event data persistent, which has security implications you may want to consider before implementing this.

The method I outlined above keeps event data transient.

Answer (score 2):

If you are lucky enough to have all of your window on the same domain then you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) as already mentioned or even better HTML5 [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). You have an article and demo available [here](http://bens.me.uk/2013/localstorage-inter-window-messaging). Mainly what's going on here :

All window listen to storage event with something like :

```
window.addEventListener("storage", handle_storage, false);
```

For every window you can have a different `handle_storage` function or a common one that checks which url is responsible for the storage event.

Advantages :

- No reference to other windows,
- WILL work even if the main window is closed,
- Standard and widely available IE8+, FF3.5+, Chrome4+,
- "Native" Javascript no external library. Easy integration within your Angular JS app

Disadvantages :

- None (at least from what I know)

Hope this will help.

Comment: I'm not clear on how this meets the non-interference requirement - I can have two instances of the application running in separate sessions and I *don't* want them interfering with each other.